# nextLine() Scanner java not working properly (possible because of Unicode)

Tags: java, unicode, java.util.scanner

I have a String in a file which is supposed to be read in using the nextLine() method in the Scanner class in the following way:

```
some_string = "All the staff in the operating room has been specifically trained with a theoretical and practical 20-hour course.\xe2\x80\xa9Results: The overall average incidence of adverse events reported was determined by 4.8%, is consistent with the expectations of the study protocol, and is at a lower level than the average median rate of international studies (8.9%).\n"
```

I create a scanner object in the following way:

```
 Scanner br = new Scanner(new File("location of my file"), "UTF-8");
```

then i get the next lines by doing:

```
while (br.hasNextLine()) {
       System.out.println(br.nextLine());
}
```

and I get:

```
>All the staff in the operating room has been specifically trained with a theoretical and practical 20-hour course.
>Results: The overall average incidence of adverse events reported was determined by 4.8%, is consistent with the expectations of the study protocol, and is at a lower level than the average median rate of international studies (8.9%).
```

It seems that nextLine() is failing when there are non ASCII characters. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes. Upon further thinking I notice that the sequence of  '\xe2\x80\xa9' is some form of paragraph splitter from here http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal

Comment: @DavidWallace Any ideas on how I can avoid anything that is not a new line character?

Comment: You could try `br.next("[^\\n]*\\n")` instead of `br.nextLine()`.  I haven't tested it so I have no idea whether it works, but given what the Javadoc says, it seems likely.  If it works, let me know and I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: That hex sequence is U+2029. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918896

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("the file"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\n");

    while (scanner.hasNext())
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Comment: thanks, but the next() method is returning a no such element exception, any ideas?

Comment: On the same line? Or is this from a different part of the file?

Comment: I am not sure unless you have closed the underlying stream - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042008/java-util-nosuchelementexception-scanner-reading-user-input

Answer (score 1):

I'm fighting right now with this problem, unfortunately Scanner doesn't work with non-ascii characters, so when it reaches a non-ascii character it acts as the file is ended. That's the reason why hasNext or hasNextLine return false!
You can change method and use BufferedReader for reading the file.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```