# Explain this line written in JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In HACKERRANK this line of code occurs very frequently. I think this is to skip whitespaces but what does that `"\r\u2028\u2029\u0085"` thing mean

```
 scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

Comment: this is a regular expression, ie. a string expressing the format/characters to match for a given operation: in this case, the scanner is asked to skip carriage return / line feeds, or one of the given unicode character (\u2028 is the unicode reference for the character "Line separator": https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm). More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: This ignores newlines. U+2028 is such a newline char.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Skip `\r\n` is for Windows.

The rest is standard `\r=CR`, `\n=LF` (see [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them))

Then some Unicode special characters:

`u2028 = LINE SEPARATOR` (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm)

`u2029 = PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR` 
(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm)

`u0085 = NEXT LINE` (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm)

Comment: This answer is more readable and concise.

Answer (score 22):

**Scanner.skip skips a input which matches the pattern, here the pattern is :-**

## (\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?

- ?  matches exactly zero or one of the previous character.
- | Alternative
- [] Matches single character present in
- \r matches a carriage return
- \n newline
- \u2028 matches the character with index 2018 base 16(8232 base 10 or 20050 base 8) case sensitive
- \u2029 matches the character with index 2029 base 16(8233 base 10 or 20051 base 8) case sensitive
- \u0085 matches the character with index 85 base 16(133 base 10 or 205 base 8) case sensitive

> 1st Alternative \r\n

- \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
- \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)

> 2nd Alternative [\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]

- Match a single character present in the list below [\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]
- \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
- \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
- \u2028 matches the character with index 202816 (823210 or 200508) literally (case sensitive) LINE SEPARATOR
- \u2029 matches the character with index 202916 (823310 or 200518) literally (case sensitive) PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
- \u0085 matches the character with index 8516 (13310 or 2058) literally (case sensitive)  NEXT LINE

Answer (score 6):

OpenJDK's source code shows that nextLine() uses this regex for line separators:

```
private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]";
```

- `\r\n` is a *Windows* line ending.
- `\n` is a *UNIX* line ending.
- `\r` is a *Macintosh* (pre-OSX) line ending.
- `\u2028` is [LINE SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).
- `\u2029` is [PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm).
- `\u0085` is [NEXT LINE (NEL)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm).

Answer (score 4):

The whole thing is a regex expression, so you could simply drop it into https://regexr.com or https://regex101.com/ and it will provided you with a full description of what each part of the regex means.

Here it is for you though:

> *(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])? /* gm
>
> **1st Capturing Group** *(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?*
>
> ? **Quantifier** — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>
> **1st Alternative** \r\n
>
> \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
>
> \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
>
> **2nd Alternative** *[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]*
>
> **Match a single character present in the list below**
>
> *[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]*
>
> *\n* matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
>
> *\r* matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
>
> *\u2028* matches the character   with index 202816 (823210 or 200508) literally (case sensitive)
>
> *\u2029* matches the character   with index 202916 (823310 or 200518) literally (case sensitive)
>
> *\u0085* matches the character  with index 8516 (13310 or 2058) literally (case sensitive)
>
> **Global pattern flags**
>
> *g modifier:* **g**lobal. All matches (don't return after first match)
>
> *m modifier:* **m**ulti line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

As for `scanner.skip` this does ([Scanner Pattern Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_skip_pattern.htm)):

> The java.util.Scanner.skip(Pattern pattern) method skips input that matches the specified pattern, ignoring delimiters. This method will skip input if an anchored match of the specified pattern succeeds.If a match to the specified pattern is not found at the current position, then no input is skipped and a NoSuchElementException is thrown.

I would also recommend reading `Alan Moore's` answer on here [RegEx in Java: how to deal with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445326/regex-in-java-how-to-deal-with-newline) he talks about new ways in Java 1.8.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ givea pattern error with this regular expression saying .. \u This token is not supported in the selected flavor

Comment: https://regexr.com found this link very useful. Generates nice explanation of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
 scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

1. in Unix and all Unix-like systems, \n is the code for end-of-line,
   \r means nothing special
2. as a consequence, in C and most languages that somehow copy it (even
   remotely), \n is the standard escape sequence for end of line
   (translated to/from OS-specific sequences as needed)
3. in old Mac systems (pre-OS X), \r was the code for end-of-line
   instead in Windows (and many old OSs), the code for end of line is 2
   characters, \r\n, in this order as a (surprising;-) consequence
   (harking back to OSs much older than Windows), \r\n is the standard
   line-termination for text formats on the Internet

> u0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)
>
> U2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
>
> U2028 LINE SEPARATOR'

The whole logic behind this is to remove the extra space and extra new line when input is from scanner

Answer (score 1):

There's already a similar question here [scanner.skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918896/java-scanner-newline-recognition). It won't skip whitespaces since the unicode char for it is not present (u0020)

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows

u2028 = [line separator](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2028)

u2029 = [paragraph separator](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2029&B1=Show)

u0085 = [next line](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0085)

Comment: there are also similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111208/1575188) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111263/1575188) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52111273/1575188)

Answer (score 1):

This ignores one [line break, see `\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Exactly the same could have been done with `\R` - sigh.

```
scanner.skip("\\R?");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a much simpler exercise to explain this

```
  public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "HackerRank ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    double b;
    String c = null;

    a = scan.nextInt();
    b = scan.nextDouble();
    c = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(c);
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(a + i);
    System.out.println(b + d);
    System.out.println(s.concat(c));
   }
}
```

TRY running this.. FIRST and see the output

After that

```
 public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    String s = "HackerRank ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    double b;
    String c = null;

    a = scan.nextInt();
    b = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
    c = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(c);
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(a + i);
    System.out.println(b + d);

    System.out.println(s.concat(c));
 }
}
```

TRY THIS AGAIN..

This can be a very tricky interview question

I cursing myself before I could realise the issue..

Just ask any programmer
to take an integer number
to take an double number
and a string 
ALL FROM USER INPUT

If they don't know this.. they will most definitely fail..

You can find a much simpler answer about the behaivor of the integer and the double in their javadocs

Comment: need to import import java.util.*;   before using the Scanner Class

Answer (score 0):

It is associated to scanner class:

Lets suppose u have input from system console

```
4
This is next line
```

---

```
int a  =scanner.nextInt();
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

value of a will be read as 4
and value of s will be empty string because nextLine just reads what is next in same line, and after that it shifts to nextLine

---

to read it perfectly, u should add one more time nextLine() like below

```
int a  =scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

---

to insure that it reaches to nextline and skips everything if there is any anomaly in the input

```
scan.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

upper line does job perfectly in every OS and environment.