# What does scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?"); do?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
```

I know about `scanner.skip()` but I don't know what exactly the above line does.
I saw it in many programs but I don't know what exactly is happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111077/explain-this-line-written-in-java

Comment: I assume you did not try googling this?

Comment: I tried but didn't got a clear picture of it.